# Why does my webpage submit the form when it loads, but no submit button has been clicked?

Tags: forms, submit

The windows.pageload event handler submits the page on page load. My intention is for this to wire the event handler to the submit event when the form submit button is clicked. What did I do wrong? Thanks!

```
function submit_data () {

var parent1Phone =              $("parent1Phone").value;

var areaCode = parent1Phone.substring(0,3);

var prefix = parent1Phone.substring(4,7);

var suffix = parent1Phone.substring(8,12);

var firstName =                     $("firstName").value;
var lastName =            $("lastName").value;
var sportID =                       $("sportID").value;
var entryFrom =                     $("entryFrom").value;
var linkSource =                    codeSource;
var primaryEmail =              $("primaryEmail").value;
var graduationYear =            $("graduationYear").value;
var postalCode =                    $("postalCode").value;
var parent1FirstName =      $("parent1FirstName").value;
var parent1LastName =       $("parent1LastName").value;
var parent1Relationship =   $("parent1Relationship").value;
var parent1Phone1=        areaCode;
var parent1Phone2 =       prefix;
var parent1Phone3 =       suffix;
var parent1PhoneType =      $("parent1PhoneType").value;                    //No validation required. No non-choice allowed.
var parent1Email =              $("parent1Email").value;
var parent1EmailConfirm =   $("parent1Email").value;
var successDestination =    success;
var errorDestination =      failure;

var url =   "http://recruit-  match.ncsasports.org/fasttrack/saefentry/submitFullFormRemote.go?";

window.location.href = url + "firstName="+ firstName + "&lastName=" + "&lastName=" + lastName +"&sportID=" + sportID + "&entryFrom=" + entryFrom + "&linkSource=" + linkSource + "&primaryEmail=" + primaryEmail +"&graduationYear=" + graduationYear + "&postalCode=" + postalCode + "&parent1FirstName=" + parent1FirstName + "&parent1LastName=" + parent1LastName + "&parent1Relationship=" + parent1Relationship + "&parent1Phone1=" + parent1Phone1 + "&parent1Phone2=" + parent1Phone2 + "&parent1Phone3=" + parent1Phone3 + "&parent1PhoneType=" + parent1PhoneType + "&parent1Email=" + parent1Email + "&parent1EmailConfirm=" + parent1Email + "&successDestination=" + successDestination + "&errorDestination=" + errorDestination;
}

function prepareEventHandlers() {
    $("frmNcsa").onclick = submit_data();
}

window.onload = function() {
    prepareEventHandlers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `submit_data` in the assignment `$("frmNcsa").onclick = submit_data();`, it should be `$("#frmNcsa").click(submit_data);`

assuming all the strings passed to the jQuery function are the ids of elements, they shold be prepended with `#`.

Comment: Thanks, but that--in all its permutations--didn't work. What did work was to remove the parenthesis around submit_data. Gezzz...go figure.  Thanks for trying. I truly appreciate the help!

Comment: @FreedomRoadPublishing I thought you was using [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/), my bad.